# Users Characteristics

Tags: sql-server, normalization

I'm really battling an issue where I have a Users table that has a growing number of user characteristics (regligion, smoking preferences, etc). The strategy I've used thus far has been to add a column for each preference that keys off onto another table.

For example, if User XYZ has a RelgionId of 3, that could mean they're Christian. At runtime, if I need their religion, I join onto another table.

This strategy has worked so far. However, I'm getting concerned about the number of columns in the tables as the number of preferences is increasing. Also, this strategy leads to many joins if I need to get all values for a single user.

I'd like to find out the most normalized way of representing this data. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: What does this have to do with "normalization"? What do you mean when you use that word?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this sort of thing by creating what are essentially property bags of these values.   This is not an approach that I am a huge fan of, but as with everything in SQL Server it has its place and your scenario might well be that case.

This is essentially the EAV approach, and Aaron Bertrand has a great writeup on this [here](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway) to describe the pros and cons in more detail

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    UserID int identity(1, 1) primary key clustered
    ,UserName varchar(200)
);

CREATE TABLE PreferenceType
(
    PreferenceTypeID int identity(1, 1) primary key clustered
    ,PreferenceName varchar(200)
);

CREATE TABLE PreferenceValue
(
    PreferenceValueID int identity(1, 1) primary key clustered
    ,PreferenceValueName varchar(200)
    ,PreferenceTypeID int
);


CREATE TABLE UserPreference
(
    UserPreferenceID int identity(1, 1) primary key clustered
    ,UserID int
    ,PreferenceValueID int
);

ALTER TABLE PreferenceValue
ADD CONSTRAINT  FKValue_Type FOREIGN KEY (PreferenceTypeID) REFERENCES PreferenceType(PreferenceTypeID);

ALTER TABLE UserPreference
ADD CONSTRAINT  FK_UserPreference_User FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID);

ALTER TABLE UserPreference
ADD CONSTRAINT  FK_UserPreference_Value FOREIGN KEY (PreferenceValueID) REFERENCES PreferenceValue(PreferenceValueID);


insert into Users (UserName)
Values ('User1' ) --tblUserID = 1
, ('User2' );   --tblUserID = 2

Insert into PreferenceType  (PreferenceName)
Values ('Religion') --Type1
, ('Smoker'); --Type 2

Insert into PreferenceValue (PreferenceValueName, PreferenceTypeID)
Values ('Christian', 1) --Value 1
, ('Muslim', 1) --Value 2
, ('Non Smoker', 2)  --Value 3
, ('Smoker' , 2); -- Value 4


--User 1 is a Christian Smoker
--User 2 is a Muslim Non-Smoker
Insert into UserPreference (UserID, PreferenceValueID)
Values (1, 1)
, (1, 4)
, (2, 2)
, (2, 3);
```

Visually:

[image]

So that when you want to get the information for User 1 you would run this select:

```
select u.UserID, u.UserName, pv.PreferenceValueName, pt.PreferenceName
From Users u
join UserPreference up on u.UserID = up.UserID
join PreferenceValue pv on up.PreferenceValueID = pv.PreferenceValueID
join PreferenceType pt on pv.PreferenceTypeID = pt.PreferenceTypeID
Where u.UserName = 'User1';
```

You would get the following results in the format of

UserID, UserName, PreferenceValue, PreferenceType

1, User1, Christian, Religion

1, User1, Smoker, Smoker

To include Date values within a schema similar to this, playing off of the tables that were already created but adding two new ones, you could do something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE DateType
(
    DateTypeID int identity(1, 1) primary key clustered
    ,DateTypeName varchar(200)
);

CREATE TABLE UserDateType
(
    UserDateTypeID int identity(1, 1) primary key clustered
    ,UserID int
    ,DateTypeID int
    ,DateValue datetime
);

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX
    uq_UserDateType on UserDateType (UserID, DateTypeID);  --Optional. To only allow one row per type.  

ALTER TABLE UserDateType
ADD CONSTRAINT  FKDateType FOREIGN KEY (DateTypeID) REFERENCES DateType(DateTypeID);

ALTER TABLE UserDateType
ADD CONSTRAINT  FKUserDate_UserID FOREIGN KEY (UserID) REFERENCES Users(UserID);


Insert into DateType (DateTypeName)
Values ('BirthDate') --Type1
, ('Anniversary'); --Type 2

Insert into UserDateType (UserID, DateTypeID, DateValue)
Values (1, 1, '01/01/1980') --User 1 has a Birthday of 01/01/1980
, (1, 2, '01/01/2000')  --User 1 has an Anniversary of 01/01/2000
, (2, 1, '02/01/1995');  --User 2 has an Birthday of 01/01/2000
```

By having these kinds of tables you can dynamically add the new date types and relate them to a user in this way.

As mentioned above, I am not sure that this is the ideal approach, as it certainly has its flaws, but this is a way that you can do this sort of thing with Date values.

Comment: Will do, all good points and thank you for commenting.

Comment: Yes... I definitely considered this approach. I'm going to run this through SQL and analyze a bit, I'll get back to you on this.

Comment: The more I look at this whole problem, the more I like your approach. It's kind of gross though in terms of noramlization and SQL principles and is without a doubt an anti-pattern. But it seems more appealing than a lookup table per property.

Comment: Where/how would I store different types of data? In this schema, every value is categorically nvarchar. What about storing int, datetime? I'm certain that an additional 'datatype', or something like that, column can be added, but where?

Comment: @mskinner Answer / edit that in, you got the check.

Comment: @user3308043 - I added in how you can do this with a Datetime and you should be able to modify for just about any date type.   It is not the pretties approach but it works if the type of data that you are storing about various attributes changes regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Normalization is a great concept and essential for well performing relational database.  However it can become counter productive.  For example you almost never see addresses broken up like this:

```
StateRegionTable    CityTable        ZipTable
   StateId             CityId           ZipId
   StateDesc           CityDesc         ZipDesc

AddressTable
   AddressId
   Address1
   Address2
   CityId
   StateId
   ZipId
```

It's just not all that useful and slows things down with extra joins.  In your case I would recommend removing extra tables where the table only has an Id/Description pair.

So instead of having a ReligionTable and a SmokingTable and a GenderTable etc just have description columns with CHECK constraints.  That does mean that if you want to add an extra value to the list you will have to modify the check constraint but with these types of tables it shouldn't happen all of that often.  Where you do NOT want to do this is when your lookup table requires extra information.  For example if your SmokingTable had an "Additional Insurance Cost" column or something like that then you want a separate lookup table.

Your table would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Users (
    UserId INT,
    Religion VARCHAR(50) CONSTRAINT ck_Users_Religion CHECK (Religion IN ('Christian','Jew','Budist')),
    SmokingPreference CHAR(3) CONSTRAINT ck_Users_Smoking CHECK (SmokingPreference IN ('YES','NO'))
    )
```

Comment: Not at all. I'm saying that you can over normalize.  Again you frequently don't see state & zip tables because while you could normalize them it just isn't worth it.  I'm only talking about cases where the lookup table would only be an ID/Description pair. Normalization is important. It can just be taken to far.

Comment: I agree with you in part, but what you're suggesting (and I do appreciate your suggestion) is an EAV anti-pattern. I've really come to realize that this is a complete trade-off type of scenario. There is no best answer.

Comment: I figured I would get a strong response on StackOverflow with this question and I did. Please look at Bill Karwin's answer.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536617/users-table-to-users-and-user-preferences-is-this-normalized/25536700?noredirect=1#comment39874902_25536700

Comment: No problem :) Although actually I'm talking about de-normalizing your data a little bit (not a lot).  An EAV is something else.  If you look at a datawarehouse structure sometime (definitely relational) you will see that they deliberately demoralize in certain places to gain reporting speed.

Comment: Could you take a look at the answer above? I'm wondering about datatypes. Could I implicitly convert nvarchar values into C# data types?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about C#.  I would bet yes though.  I would be very surprised if C# didn't have a unicode string data type.

Comment: I'm looking to add another field somewhere in the schema in the answer above that also includes the datatype of the answer. Like, is the value int/bool/string? Any idea how that could fit into the schema? I've added another table that stores it and I think that's best way to go, but I'd like for somebody with a bit more experience with this EAV style to perhaps comment.

Comment: It's one of the major down sides to doing that type of schema.  You have no good ways to deal with numeric and date values.  I've done EAV type formats before but usually I've just bitten the bullet and had 3 or 4 different columns in the table, one of each data type.  Over the years I've learned it didn't work terribly well and stopped using EAV type formats in general.

Comment: Yes, I hate this EAV nonsense. The only other solution for me seems to be table per user property. But that just seems like it will get ugly. Really ugly.

Comment: I still feel that denormalizing to a small extent is your best bet. Look at a datawarehouse and you will see they denormalize (and for good reason) and in fact for what you are doing most databases I've seen do as well.

Comment: I agree with you. One of the reasons I like the lookup tables is that I can easily query them when I need all of the values. That becomes more abstracted if I were to use check constraints.

Comment: It seems to me as if I've got either one of two choices. Either use EAV and have to deal with large pivots or use the lookup tables and have to deal with large joins. I heavily prefer the lookup tables, I just don't like the mess is a schema it produces. I may be able to splinter off the main table to reduce table size and to organize. Major pivots could be an issue with EAV. It seems like either way is a performance issue.

Comment: Do you have access to the application code as well as the DB? If so you could use a lookup table to hold the choices allowed in the table.  It's not as strong a link as a foreign key but you still have your lookup table and as long as no one is entering data directly into the table it should still be consistent.

Comment: I do have access to the code and DB. The Users table itself has many simple lookups (lots of them). Would it be rational to splinter these lookups off of the main table and then use a view to create this lookup table? More specifically, could I combine all of these lookup tables into a view (or views?) effectively?